# Run ls command inside ssh

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script something like below

```
sshpass -p "pwd" ssh -tt user@host << EOF  
cd /directory  
file=$(ls -1t| head -1)  
exit  
EOF
```

`cd /directory` is changing the directory successfully inside shell. But `ls` gives the result which is outside the shell. The result of `ls` is same as when executed outside `ssh`. Please help in this.

Answer (score 3):

The `$(...)` part is being evaluated by the outer shell. You can disable this by quoting `'EOF'` so that `$(...)` is passed to the remote shell. It's akin to using single quotes instead of double quotes with regular strings.

```
sshpass -p "pwd" ssh -tt user@host << 'EOF'  
cd /directory  
file=$(ls -1t| head -1)  
exit  
EOF
```